# Pull to refresh view not dismissing when used to trigger a segue

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh

I want to use a pull-to-refresh UI action to trigger a segue to a modal view. The action works fine, triggering the modal segue as expected. But when I dismiss the modal, the refresh control view is still visible.

I am correctly calling `refreshControl.endRefreshing()` before the segue, but the problem seems to be that the UI doesn't have time to complete the animation that dismisses the refresh control view before the segue is trigger, so it gets suck half way.

If I place a small delay (0.4s) before triggering the segue this kind of helps, as it allows the animation to complete, but it feels like a hack. Also, if the user pulls down really slowly on the tableview, and releases the pull-down later than after 0.4 seconds, the same problem occurs.

How can I ensure that the refresh control will not be visible when I dismiss the modal view? Ideas I have (but which I can't find a way to implement) include:
1) ensuring the animation that dismisses the refresh control has time to complete before the segue is triggered.
2) dismiss the refresh control view on the parent view when I dismiss the modal.

I can't get either of the above to work though.
With 1) a delay works (sometimes), but feels like a hack.
With 2) tableView.reloadData() only reloads the tableview, not the whole view, so the refresh control remains.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that implements the refresh control.

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {

    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pullToAddCard(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    return refreshControl
}()
```

And here is the code that gets triggered by the refresh control

```
 @objc func pullToAddCard(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    delay(0.4, closure: {
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueFromPlaylistDetailToNewCard", sender: self)

    })

}
```

And here is a screenshot of what the parent view looks like when I nav back to it (by dismissing the modal view.) The 'stuck' refresh control view is visible at the top.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. @Ashley Mills' answer gave me an idea. In `viewWillAppear` I call `refreshControl.beginRefreshing()`, and then immediately call `refreshControl.endRefreshing()`, and that works!

For some reason, simply calling `refreshControl.endRefreshing()` wasn't enough.

Comment: just calling `refreshControl.endRefreshing()` isn't enough, you need to check if the control flow goes to the position where you have invoked that. 

`viewWillAppear` is always invoked that's why `refreshContol.endRefreshing` works.

Comment: You can handle it with call  if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing{//do something }

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
```

to your `viewWillAppear` method

---

I just tried the following using the storyboard below, and it works fine…

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        refreshControl?.endRefreshing()        
    }

    @IBAction func unwind(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {            
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ashley Mills but I just double checked and for some reason your solution doesn't work for me. But it did give me an idea. See my answer. If you have any idea why calling `beginRefreshing()` immediately before `endRefreshing()` solves the problem, I would be very interested to know.